# Regex validation for number, dash and square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I need to validate below format using jquery/javascript regex validation.

It is done in java regex using code :

```
"(\\d{1,2})?\\s?\\[\\d{3}\\]\\s?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}"
```

but now require in javascript/jquery at client side.

Below are samples :

```
1) 1 [123] 1234-5678
2) 1[123] 1235-5678
3) 1[123]1236-5678
4) 1 [123]1237-5678
5) 1 [123] 12385789
6) 1[123]12341678
7) 1 [123]12345678
8) 1[123] 1234-5678
9) [123] 1234-5678
10) [123]1234-5678
11) [123]12345678
12) [123] 12345678
```

Its basically combination of number, square brackets, dash,
here number & square bracket must exist but dash(-) may or may not.

Only number & square brackets can allowed, no else characters

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: what  can be the regex to validate using javascript/jquery

Comment: Ok, actually now I need is to validation at client side instead of java regex.

Comment: You can use `/^(\d{1,2})?\s?\[\d{3}\]\s?\d{4}-?\d{4}$/` or `new RegExp("^(\\d{1,2})?\\s?\\[\\d{3}\\]\\s?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}$")` - http://regexr.com/3at5j

Comment: Gr8..! It is workin fine for all samples. You can also answer this question using your comment. 

Thank You ! I appreciate your help, you saved my time..!

Comment: Please don't tag-spam.  `ajax` and the jQuery Validation plugin has nothing to do with this question.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JS, you can use a RegExp object literal which means that you don't need to escape the backslash characters. A RegExp object literal can be created by surrounding a regex expression by two forward slash characters:

Original regex:

```
"(\\d{1,2})?\\s?\\[\\d{3}\\]\\s?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}"
```

Assigning a variable to a RegExp object in JavaScript:

```
var myRegex = /(\d{1,2})?\s?\[\d{3}\]\s?\d{4}-?\d{4}/;
```

Any flags you want to add to the regex (g, i, m, y) should go directly after the terminating forward slash. Ex:

```
/(\d{1,2})?\s?\[\d{3}\]\s?\d{4}-?\d{4}/gm
```

Another way of doing it would be to take your original regex in string form and pass it into a RegExp constructor, but this is only recommended for dynamic regular expressions instead of static ones:

```
var myRegex = new RegExp('(\\d{1,2})?\\s?\\[\\d{3}\\]\\s?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}');
```

You can also optionally pass in a second argument to this constructor which takes a string of flags.

More documentation on creating and using RegExp objects can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses actual RegExp instead of it in a string. You can make this into a Regular Expression using the `RegExp` class:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(\\d{1,2})?\\s?\\[\\d{3}\\]\\s?\\d{4}-?\\d{4}");
```

`regex` now holds your regex. Using this, you can exchange regex back and fourth without having to modify them. Javascript also supports RegEx with `/` in the front, and end.

```
var regex = /(?:This\sIs\sMy\sRegex)/flags;
```